# Can I use closest() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the `closest()` function to delete a row from a table, but I am encountering an error.

Call function:`<button onclick="validarIntervencao(1)">test</button>`

```js
function validarIntervencao(id) {
  var element = this;

  $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirmação!',
    content: "Quer mesmo validar a intervenção nº" + id + "? Esta ação envia o relatório ao cliente.",
    buttons: {
      Confirmar: {
        text: 'Confirmar',
        btnClass: 'btn btn-success',
        action: function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "intervencoes/validarIntervencao/" + id,
            success: function(data) {

              if (data == false) {
                $.confirm({
                  title: 'Atenção!',
                  content: "Verifique a descrição e o relatório.",
                  buttons: {
                    Ok: {
                      text: 'Ok',
                      btnClass: 'btn btn-success'
                    }
                  }
                });
              } else {
                element.closest('tr').remove();
              }
            },
            error: function() {
              alert('Erro!');
            }
          });
        }
      },
      Cancelar: {
        text: 'Cancelar',
        btnClass: 'btn btn-danger'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<table id="intervencoesTable" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Teste</th>
    <th>Ações</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="validarIntervencao(1)" id="validaBTN1">test</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <button onclick="validarIntervencao(2)" id="validaBTN2">test</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting this error in console:

> TypeError: element.closest is not a function

Can I use the `closest()` function inside a JavaScript function? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Maybe? [Support is pretty good across modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest).

Comment: how do you call `validarIntervencao`?

Comment: `element` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: I guess you do not want to assign ``this`` to ``element``, but the element with the id provided through the argument to the function? In this case do ``let element = $("#"+id)``

Comment: @seantunwin first line of the function. If it wasn't declared the error would be different

Comment: Fair enough, but is `this` an element?

Comment: @Thomas `onclick="validarIntervencao(1)"`

Comment: That's a more valid point. It's definitely *something*, otherwise the error would be 'cannot read property closest of undefined'

Comment: @RaulReis if you're calling this function from an inline event handler `this` will refer to the `window`, hence there is no `closest()` parent element as it's the top level. If you use an unobtrusive event handler then `this` will work correctly as you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another parameter to your function which will pass the element clicked.

```html
<button onclick="validarIntervencao(this, 1)">test</button>
```

```js
function validarIntervencao(element,id) {...}
```

This will allow you to remove the `element = this;` declaration.

Comment: While this is the quick and dirty fix, it's not best practice.

Comment: Agreed. Although it does answer the question with minimal architectural refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

You state in the comment that you're calling this function from an inline `onclick` attribute. This is the problem.

When invoked in this manner `this` within the function will refer to the `window`, which has no `closest()` method, as it's the top level object in the DOM.

To fix this issue, and improve the quality of your code, remove the `onclick` attribute and  invoke your logic from an unobtrusive event handler. The handler function will run under the scope of the element which raised the event, so `this` will work as you expect it to. Try this:

```js
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    // $.confirm( ... 
    var button = e.target;
    button.closest('tr').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be better to name the anonymous function, or create a handler function to call, to eliminate the possibility of re-applying the same event listener to the same element.

Comment: It's not possible to apply the same event handler to a given element multiple times with the above example. It runs once on page load.

Comment: I was saying in case there is further DOM manipulation in the app, such adding a new row and for some reason cycling through the table and calling your example later, when the element already exists and has a listener applied. In that case it will be applied multiple times with an anonymous function.

Comment: It wouldn't in this case as I've applied a single delegated event handler to the table. Any new rows will automatically work with this due to event propagation.